# How do I move a directory to another internal SDD?

Tags: dual-boot, permissions, hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. Using Ubuntu I downloaded a 2 GB directory, which now resides on the same SDD with Ubuntu — `sdb`.

But that directory was meant to be used on `sda`, which is where Windows 10 is installed. I thought I would copy that folder to `sda` using my GUI file manager and then reboot into Windows 10.

But when I copy the directory and try to paste the corresponding menu item is grayed out. Also “Create Folder” menu item is grayed out as well. The disk is mounted. I am far from being expert but when I reviewed permissions it looks like my user is allowed to modify the disk.

Comment: with the mv command?  (Is it any error that is displayed when running that?)  E.g if your folder is called  "MyFiles" :  mv /path/to/MyFiles /path/to/Other/Destination

Comment: Thanks, how do I specify another sdd in the path? I was only taught to go up to root.

Comment: mv /path/to/MyFiles /dev/yourssd  (Look up your drive you want to copy TO  with, for example df --human-readable) Or,  trough  gnome-disks,   Or  lsblk   :)

Answer (score 0):

- Figure out which sdd Windows 10 is installed on: This can be done using the command `sudo lsblk` and look for the windows partition.
- Next type in `sudo mv /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY /mnt/sda{step one}/Users/WINDOWSUSERNAME/`